# Create ONE callback for all page templates, post filter queries + paginated pages, triggering pagination via AJAX

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, pagination

I'm querying posts using the following wp query:

```
function custom_retrieve_posts_function() {

$paged = get_query_var( "paged" ) ? get_query_var( "paged" ) : 1;
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'paged' => $paged
);
$query = new \WP_Query( $args );
$output = "";
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // Iterate next post of query result
    $query->the_post();

    $output .= get_the_content();

  }

  // Only display arrows if links have been obtained, so do it in this way
  $previous_link = get_previous_posts_link(
    esc_html__( 'Zurück', 'custom-text-domain' )
  );
  
  $next_link = get_next_posts_link(
    esc_html__( 'Weiter', 'custom-text-domain' ),
    $query->max_num_pages
  );

  $nav_links = "<div id=\"navigation-links\">".

    "<span id=\"previous-link\">".
    ( $previous_link ? "&#8678 {$previous_link}" : "" ).
    "</span>".

    "<span id=\"next-link\">".
    ( $next_link ? "{$next_link} &#8680" : "" ).
    "</span>".

  "</div>";

  $output .= $nav_links;

  // Reset the wp_query loop
  wp_reset_postdata();
      
 } else {

   $output = "<p class=\"no-results\">Oops!</p>";

}

echo $output;

}
```

Problem is that certain posts of page n are seemingly randomly repeated on page(s) m, with m > n.

The amount / limit of posts to be shown in feeds and blogs is 7, I've set that in the wp admin options. Still, same problem persists.

Any idea why this is happening?

***UPDATE***

The function `custom_retrieve_posts_function()` (defined in a namespace within a class etc., but all of this is omitted here for simplicity) is called within a PHP script bound to the AJAX hook responsible for executing a custom filtered query via ajax.

So the script is called like this:

Main Plugin File holds this:

```
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_myplugin_search_custom',
  function() {
    require MYPLUGIN_AJAX_DIR.'/custom_search.php';
    wp_die();
  }
);

add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nopriv_myplugin_search_custom',
  function() {
    require MYPLUGIN_AJAX_DIR.'/custom_search.php';
    wp_die();
  }
);
```

With the content of `AJAX_DIR.'/custom_search.php'` being (again simplified, all naming conflicts are 100% avoided, so all classnames / namespaces are again omitted):

```
check_ajax_referer( 'ajax-nonce-content' );
require MYPLUGIN.'/custom_search_function.php';
custom_retrieve_posts_function();
```

I then also have a page template defined in my `themes/mycustomtheme/templates` directory, and within that page template, I simply call

```
require MYPLUGIN.'/custom_search_function.php';
custom_retrieve_posts_function();
```

Note that all of this works perfectly, expect from the problem that already displayed posts are re-displayed on subsequently paginated pages.

***UPDATE 2***

Sadly, I'm not able to make it working after making the commented adaptations via js (additionally pass the number of the page of the pagination to query). Like when I do this query via AJAX:

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'my_post_type',
        'tax_query' => $tax_query_array,
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'my_metas_key',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'paged' => 2
);
```

I still get one of the posts already shown on page 1 (a random one).

Same if I add `$args['offset'] = 7` and / or `$args['page'] = 2`, so I'm confused; what am I still not properly understanding here??

Comment: is there a reason you're using a secondary custom query instead of modifying the main query with `pre_get_posts` to change its parameters? Pagination functions in WordPress all work off of the main query by default. Also if the main query has 4 pages but your query has 5, then the 5th page may not work as you expected because there is not 5th page on the main query. You might find it 404's instead. Also what file is this in? Is it a page template? Are you trying to build a CPT archive? What is it trying to implement?

Comment: This loop is called in a callback which is called from the frontend via AJAX (correctly setup wp-ajax) request to query for specific posts using values provided via the frontend. Does that help you? I'm unaware about the fact that WP has different kinds of queries (```main``` and not-```main```, seemingly), but thought, the [docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Removing_query_posts_from_the_Main_Loop) say you should use the ```WP_Query``` class for page templates, so I'll most likely also use it in ajax calls..?

Comment: To be precise, I use this callback both on a page template (I simply call the callback from within the page template) and an ajax request, fired from the frontend via that same page to do the above-mentioned.

Comment: Ah! So there is no main query because AJAX. The main query is the query that was created using the parameters generated by the URL + rewrite rules, and is what functions such as `the_post` or `have_posts` etc refer to, much like there's a current post. If your query is inside an AJAX callback that's super important information, AJAX requests do not have pagination, you have to provide it. It looks like you have not provided the full code, you'll need to edit your question to include this. Don't try to be helpful and hide things you think aren't relevant, that's probably were the error was

Comment: Also note that the first paragraph of the doc you linked to is mainly talking about how it breaks pagination, and how it is _not_ the best way to modify the default query.

Comment: Not sure if that's what you want, but I've added the code above, simply adding the hooking and showing how I call the function via the ajax script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of this line:

```php
$paged = get_query_var( "paged" ) ? get_query_var( "paged" ) : 1;
```

This is inside a function that is used on both an AJAX handler, and on a page request. `get_query_var` pulls the parameters from the main query ( aka the primary `WP_Query` that powers functions such as `the_post`, `have_posts()` etc ). But this will **never** work in an AJAX request.

For this reason, when you request the next page from AJAX it will always result in page `1`. If you want something other than page 1 then you need to include the number of the page you want in the javascript that sends the AJAX request, pass it along, then read it and put it in the `WP_Query` parameters directly. Even if there was a main query it would not be the same main query.

Remember, every request to the server loads WordPress from a blank slate, AJAX request handlers share nothing with the page that your browser has open unless you explicitly send them the data you want to share along with the request as POST/GET variables. There is no shared pagination state behind the scenes or magic that glues it together.

Additionally, because you included the pagination HTML in the AJAX response you'll now have a next page link that leads to page 2, but triggers AJAX that loads page 1 ( why would it know to load page 2? `get_query_var` won't work, there is no main query to get a query var from! ).

---

What's more, I have a strong suspicion that you're either unaware of `archive-mycustompost.php`, the `pre_get_posts` filter, or the ability to change the URL of the CPT archive when registering the CPT, or that query parameters for the main query come from the URL and you can add extra parameters e.g. `example.com/?s=test&posts_per_page=7&paged=2` gets the second page of a search query for "Test" that has 7 posts per page. In the majority of cases a secondary query and a custom page template are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Well the thing is that sometimes it actually works, and only the subsequent posts are shown on the subsequently paginated pages. But this seems to be completely independent of cache / sessions whatsoever, which is why I figured there must be sth I'm doing wrong. So you're telling me that there's no way to do what I want / that I need to fire an AJAX request for every single pagination?

Comment: And, if I'm not wrong, the "paged" query var should be retrieved from the links generated via the ```get_next_posts_links()``` and the ```get_previous_posts_links()``` called within my callback; because when I click on them, it indeed adds the ```page/2/``` etc. slugs onto the URL and reloads the page. Maybe I should follow the approach of the ```paged``` parameter for static front pages, I'll give it a try, one sec (what I mean is [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Static_Front_Page)).

Comment: I suspect there is some confusion here and inconsistency in the information you have given. This answer is written under the assumption that the code your provided is inside PHP executed in a WP AJAX handler, and _only_ in a WP AJAX handler, is this correct? Remember, `get_previous_posts_links` etc all refer to the main query, but AJAX request handlers do not have a main query. Also your last comment contradicts the comment about this being AJAX. Can you clarify unambiguously?

Comment: I see your edit updates, I will adjust my answer but you will not like the result

Comment: No, as stated in my ```UPDATE``` section above, it's a callback written in a separate php file, say ```filter.php```. I then call the function of ```filter.php``` from within the page template (so no AJAX at the very first call), then there's a filter mask which the client can use to filter for posts (if triggered, the function in ```filter.php``` is called from within a WP AJAX handler, hooked as shown above). Is that clearer? Sorry for not being precise at the start..

Comment: Using [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination#Static_Front_Page) did not do the trick :(

Comment: Do you have any links to cool docs which describe this mechanism of wordpress that it has with ```main query``` and secondary queries, as you stated? It's astonishing and frustrating that I've never actually heard about this.

Comment: Why would it? That code is not intended for AJAX requests. As I said, in an AJAX request there is no main query, which means there is nowhere to pull query variable from _because there are no query variables in an AJAX request_. So `get_query_var('paged')` will never work, therefore your check always returns 1 in AJAX

Comment: @DevelJoe literally anywhere that refers to the main loop is referring to the main query, literally any query that was created by using `new WP_Query()`, `query_posts` or `get_posts` or one of the other functions is not the main query. It's one of the most foundational fundamental beginner level things you should have learnt, so basic that it may never have been directly mentioned because custom queries were introduced instead as custom queries.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/#creating-secondary-queries-and-loops, but as I said, if there is no main query, there are no query variables, so no pagination. It's your responsibility to provide that information, it's not something that code inside an AJAX handler can figure out, it has to be told.

Comment: ```AJAX request handlers share nothing with the page that your browser has open unless you explicitly send them the data you want to share along with the request as POST/GET variables. There is no shared pagination state behind the scenes or magic that glues it together.``` Sadly, when developing this, it worked on the few first times, which is why I supposed that wordpress actually implements this kind of magic. So sad to know that I was terribly wrong :')

Comment: Yes it's absolute nonsense that AJAX kind of keeps that information across page loads^^

Comment: The ```archive-custom-post.php``` template is not a viable solution for this case, as the page is not a page specific to the custom post type. I also wanted to avoid extensive URL params, as the query holds like up to 8 different tax query parameters, meta k-v pairs, an order clause etc. (all displayed in my link), so the resulting links would be somewhat horrible.

Comment: So I guess including an additional ```paged``` parameter in my AJAX trigger on the js-side is the easiest way to reach what I want, not really a big deal. As I see it, I need to send all of the query parameters on every pagination to the server anyway, so if I can choose among using like 10 ```$_GET``` params or 10 ```$_POST``` params via AJAX, I'll prefer the solution across AJAX, tbh. This also avoids the need of reloading the entire page on every pagination (believe it or not, as the query was really fast, I've only noticed that now..).

Comment: Anyway, thx a lot for your help, all of this will drastically improve the project anyways, and I'll be careful with using AJAX in case of WP pagination in the future, and maybe rather change the templating approach!

Comment: And just to double-check, this means that, if you ever query posts via AJAX, you should indeed do that using ```WP_Query()```, ```query_posts()``` or ```get_posts()```, as the main query is not available in WP AJAX. correct?

Comment: And from what I additionally understood after going through the theme dev docs you've provided, I should actually not use any of those whenever I'm retrieveing data on page loads of template files, and instead always use the main query in that case. So the main query is executed on every page load, and with every call to ```WP_Query()```, ```query_posts()``` and / or ```get_posts()```, you're actually making an additional Post query. Is that correct?

Comment: `archive-custom-post.php` _is_ specific to that CPT, it's the fact that the query is for a specific CPT that leads WP to loading that file, I suspect your model of why WP loads a template and why it loads posts is upside down. URL gets parsed by -> rewrite rules into query params -> which go into the main WP_Query -> which fetches the posts -> which are then displayed by a template chosen based on the parameters of WP_Query. Also never used `query_posts`, and `get_posts` uses `WP_Query` internally. And yes, on the frontend there is always a main query, any query you create is a new query

Comment: so for your page at `/xyz`, the URL matches a rewrite rule for pages, which turns it into `index.php?name=xyz` which becomes `WP_Query( ['name' => 'xyz' ] )`, which fills out some parameters internally, e.g. that it's a page and it's singular. WP fetches the posts, goes through the template hierarchy picking the most specific template it can based on what the main query says e.g. `is_search()`? or `is_archive()`? It sees it's for a page, singular, and has a template, and loads your PHP file to display the data it fetched, expecting a standard main post loop

Comment: so yeah, you're going to need to add extra steps to that page to get it searching how you wanted anyway so the URL will look a bit ugly, but even if the CPT specific archive wasn't CPT specific, `pre_get_posts` lets you change all the parameters anyway, you can just change the value of `post_type` (which you might already be doing unawares which is why you get other post types on that archive that shouldn't be there). Even then, this is what rewrite rules help with

Comment: also, look at the REST API, a lot of what you're trying to do involves fetching data that is already available at prebuilt endpoints with pretty URLs, instead you've built it with the legacy AJAX API. Why not make a request to `/wp-json/wp/v2/your-post-type` instead? And get a nice JSON object with all the CPT's ready made for javascript to work with? And human friendly error messages if you make a mistake, and adding/updating with `POST`, and all the parameters like `?s=` etc. If you mess up the WP AJAX API you just get a `0` :|

Comment: Thx s lot. The thing is that I've developed a fancy way using the legacy AJAX API via js which is much easier for customization and error handling of the request for me, once setup. Also, to setup the REST calls in a dynamic way to behave such as ajax, wp recommends the use of extensions such as backbone as far as I know, and yeah I'm not allowed to use any foreign js in this project..

Comment: And for the archive / pre_get_posts logic, it may seem upside down to you, but if you knew the relationships among the different categories of that same ctp etc, you would understand why it's much faster to do it in this way in my case, and that using archives etc would be a lil overkill. Make one extra query for 7 posts per page load seems to be a fair compromise to me ^^

Comment: And it's also better from a programming perspective to have one callback which can be used for both the page templateS (!) and the requests. And to see if there's a next / previous page, it seems like I can still call the get_the_previous_posts and the get_the_next_posts, even with a ```WP_Query``` (easiest to check if there should be a next AJAX link or not, in my case, I guess). I completely get your points but in this case, I figured using a non traditional approach is better. But thx, without you, especially the notion of the main query, I'd been stuck on this for much longer.

Comment: Or are you saying to trigger rest requests via ajax, is that what you mean?

Comment: And just saw that backbone is now native wp js, was that always the case? Will keep it in mind..

Comment: I do not know where you read that WP recommends the use of extensions such as backbone, it does not, I suspect the material you're reading is extremely old and out of date. Perhaps ancient codex articles? If this were 2010 I would understand but the codex was retired many years ago in favor of the devhub and handbooks

Comment: and no a `pre_get_posts` filter is not overkill, what you did is overkill. `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ($q ) { if ( $q->is_main_query() && $q->is_archive('your-cpt' ) ) { $q->set( 'posts_per_page', 7 ); } } );`

Comment: As for REST APIs, it's literally just AJAX but to a nicer API that has pretty URLs and speaks in JSON by default. There is no reason to use the old legacy `admin-ajax.php` API in modern WordPress, the REST API does it all and better. You can also safely ignore backbone JS, only time you would need it is if you modified the upload/media library modal dialog.

Comment: I would ignore the Codex and instead use the official docs at https://developer.wordpress.org/

Comment: I misexplained myself or you misunderstood me, I mean setting up the archive pages with the pre_get_posts filter etc. is overkill for what I need to do in my application, as all the rest (AJAX handlers, query function on page load etc.) is all set up and all I have to do is add a POST parameter in js to stick to my entire design. But I agree that by default it's definitely the better approach, I agree with you on that. And thx for the docs, I indeed read about the backbone js extension in the codex, but was a while ago.

Comment: No, [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/) it still mentions the backbone js library, at the link you've shown. It was and still appeared much easier to me to setup the client part in WP AJAX rather than WP REST. What do you use to trigger REST calls in js in WP applications, if I may ask? It's clear that the PHP part is much simpler via REST, but is it the same for js??

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, it's not telling you to use backbone, it's just using it as an example. Think of it like Apple providing a USB-C to HDMI dongle, it doesn't mean they're saying all Apple customers should buy and use that dongle to use their machines properly then go buy HDMI monitors, it's just an option that's there is you already use that tech. Unless you already have a backbone codebase or intend to use backbone then the backbone client library is irrelevant to you.

Comment: As for how I trigger REST API calls, I do not understand, it's just a HTTP request to a  URL, except instead of making a request to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` I make a request to `/wp-json/tomjn/v1/myendpoint`, using exactly the same mechanism. It's still AJAX, it's not a special new type of request. E.g. `jQuery.get( 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', function ( posts ) { .... } )`, you can even load it in the browser and you can see standard JSON that any javascript can parse, just like an WP AJAX handler that returns JSON

Comment: REST API endpoints are just webpages that return machine readable data. Just like `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` is a PHP file that returns machine readable data. Except the REST API has nicer registration functions, pretty URLs, pre-built endpoints, and support for a lot of things like built in error handling, sanitising, authentication etc. There is literally nothing the admin AJAX API can do that the REST API can't.

Comment: So basically you could for example trigger a WP REST endpoint via an [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), is it that what you're trying to tell me? I know that, that's what I meant when asking ```Or are you saying to trigger rest requests via ajax, is that what you mean?``` in one of my comments above. And I'll definitely stick to that approach in pages where the entire error handling of the request + the response handling has not been setup in vanillajs, as it's the case for the concerned project.. Sorry if I misexpressed myself somewhere..

Comment: Yes, the REST API's transport layer is standard HTTP, your JS communicates with it via AJAX aka HTTP requests triggered by javascript asynchronously. There is no magic sauce. REST API's indicate failure using standard HTTP codes such as `200`/`500`, and use standard HTTP methods, e.g. you delete an item using HTTP `DELETE`, and get items with `GET` and update/create them with `POST`

Comment: Yes I know :') I've asked about the client method you use to fire the request because I found it weird that WP's dev docs explain WP AJAX by showing the client side as the traditional js AJAX code, and the server code as the according PHP + Hooking. However, the REST API documents particularly the server-side syntax, but when it comes to the client syntax, it refers to libraries. That's what initially confused me, and gave me the impression that the REST API from wp needs some kind of particular client-side stuff to fire actually simple HTTP request. Hence my questions, you see?^^

Comment: You know I just completely misunderstood the docs, it clearly says 'Any programming language which can make HTTP requests and interpret JSON can use the REST API to interact with WordPress, from PHP, Node.js, Go, and Java, to Swift, Kotlin, and beyond.' Thx anyway for all of your explanations! Clearly underestimated WP here..

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally got this working. For reasons I will not detail here, I preferred a pagination solution which uses ONE single callback which I use everywhere where I need the pagination. In other words, I call the callback call on both upon page load of the template pages needing the query AND as well when click on a pagination link OR applying any search filter to query for the posts.

In cases which do not require you to do this, of course you can refer to the discussion among @Tom J Nowell and me (in his answer above, thx again!). If possible with your design, you thus may use the WP REST API (instead of using the AP AJAX API) to create the request, an archive page + WP's main query loop + the related pagination features associated to that main query.

If you prefer to create a WP pagination solution which uses exclusively WP AJAX via `$_POST`, you can easily do this by providing the additional number of the page you're requesting to your ajax handler via JS, and simply use 1 if none is provided. So my function above became:

```
function custom_retrieve_posts_function( $paged = 1 ) {

if ( isset($_POST['page_to_request'] ) ) {
  $paged = intval( sanitize_text_field( isset( $_POST['page_to_request'] ) ) );
}

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
  'tax_query' => $tax_query_array,
  'orderby' => array(
    'meta_value_num' => 'ASC',
    'date' => 'DESC'
   ),
   'meta_key' => 'my_custom_meta_key',
   'posts_per_page' => 7,
   'paged' => $paged
);

$query = new \WP_Query( $args );
$output = "";
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    // Iterate next post of query result
    $query->the_post();

    $output .= get_the_content();

  }

  // Only display arrows if links have been obtained, so do it in this way
  $max_num_pages = $query->max_num_pages;

  $nav_links = "<div id=\"navigation-links\">".

    // If we're not on the first page, add a link allowing to go back to
    // the one previous to the one currently requested
    "<span id=\"previous-link\"".(
      ( $max_num_pages !== 1 ) ?
      " data-previous-page='".( $paged - 1 )."'>&#8678 Back" :
      ">"
    ).
    "</span>".

    // If we're not on the last page, add a link allowing to go forward to
    // the page subsequent to the one currently requested 
    "<span id=\"next-link\"".(
      ( $max_num_pages > $paged ) ?
      " data-next-page='".( $paged + 1 )."'>Next &#8680" :
      ">"
    ).
    "</span>".

  "</div>";

  $output .= $nav_links;

  // Reset the wp_query loop
  wp_reset_postdata();
      
 } else {

   $output = "<p class=\"no-results\">Oops!</p>";

}

echo $output;

}
```

Note that I've added `date` into my `order` clause, additionally to what's been specified in my question above. This is because I've found out that page n of your pagination may show posts of previous pages m where m < n, if you have many posts which have the same meta value. Even using the offset parameter of the wp query etc. will not eliminate this problem. So I thought of first using the ordering I need in my case (the meta key), and then subsequently according to another value which is unique to posts, such as the posts' date. My thought was that like this I can assure that the posts will always be retrieved in exactly the same order, even if their meta value is the same. And well, to have the same order is crucial for proper pagination, no matter the context in which the function is called.

As I imagine, WP transforms this WP_Query array into a SQL query to query for the according data. So, when using a data field which is unique to a post, but not a date but sth like a primary key in the DB, this may result in faster query times. Hence, instead of the `date` order key, you may use `ID`.